# Populate add_arguments() from an array/dict object in Python argparse

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to pre-define an `array/dict` object and loop through it for populating the `add_arguments()` command.

This is because I have flags that I use in every `subparsers.add_parser`

I.e something like:

```
repeat_args = [
  { 'nargs': 1, "help": "this is help", "dest": "var1", "metavar": "$ADD" }
  { 'nargs': 1, "help": "this is help2", "dest": "var2", "metavar": "$REMOVE" }
]

for r in repeat_args:
   parser.add_argument('-list', r)
```

But it gives me the error

```
  File "*****/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1267, in add_argument
  File "*****/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1393, in _get_optional_kwargs
KeyError: 0
```

Any ideas how to pull that off ?

Even better - if the '-list' argument can be dynamic too - but I couldn't do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you didn't know about unpacking a dictionary with the double-splat operator, like `**r`.

Something like this should give you the idea:

```
repeat_args = [
    ('foo', {'nargs': 1, 'help': 'help for foo'}),
    ('--bar', {'nargs': 1, 'help': 'help for bar'}),
]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
for argname, argoptions in repeat_args:
    parser.add_argument(argname, **argoptions)
```

Comment: haha, you're right - I didn't know, but I was actually playing with * and ** but it gave strange errors - because my structure was different than yours - works like a charm - you've made my day ! thank you very much !

Comment: btw, I've adjusted the "argname" in your example from 'foo' to ['--list', '-l'] to support more flag options - and I had to change the "argname" -> *argname, what's the difference between your **argoptions and my *argname ? ( why **argname doesn't work ? )

Comment: Your change was correct.  `*` is to unpack sequences (lists, tuples...)  and `**` is to unpack mappings (dicts).  i.e. `*args` will unpack a sequence of args to *positional arguments*, and `**kwargs` unpacks keys and values to *keyword arguments*.